# umlauts from .txt file to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, escaping

I'm reading data from a local .txt file and put it into the HTML body by .innerHTML. Basically its working but i got problems displaying umlauts (ä,ö,ü,...)

```
document.getElementById('textbox2').innerText = "äöü";
```

causes no problem, but as soon, as the text i want to display originates from the txtfile umlaut will be displayed as questionmarkboxes

```
document.getElementById('textbox2').innerText = txtFileContentContainingUmlauts;
```

I tried a lot of combinations to replace the txtfile content by escape sequences:

```
...txtFileContentContainingUmlauts.replace("ä", "\u00c4");
```

and vice versa, but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Note: I´m using Notepad++; encoding is utf-8; i set the charset in header and script to "utf-8"

Comment: I would suspect that the encoding in your text file is not UTF-8.

Comment: How to you get the content of the file?

Comment: Note: your first and last example are not UTF-8. Javascript do no use UTF-8 internally (or maybe it use it, but as if it were UTF-16).

Comment: seems like the comment of Arndt leads to the right path...just have to figure out how to get around that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was just the encoding of the .txtfile itself. Recreating it in Notepad and solved all the problems...
Thanks to Arndt.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get the file content to HTML? I tried to load a file content from file input and it works for me.

```js
function fileChanged() {
  var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
      document.getElementById("fileContents").innerText = evt.target.result;
    };
    reader.onerror = function(evt) {
      document.getElementById("fileContents").innerText = "error reading file";
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  
  <form id="form">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="fileChanged()" />
  </form>
  <div id="fileContents"><i>file content will be displayed here</i></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: exactly like that. I think its some inconsistency with the original txt encoding...